# Which is greater: $a^n! $ or $a^{n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Out of pure curiosity, I have thought about the following:

"Let $a > 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Which is greater: $a^n! $ or $a^{n!}$ ? And how do you prove it?"

Does anyone know a good/simple proof?

Comment: Maybe you want to add something like “$n$ sufficiently large”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the relationship between $a$ and $n$.

For all $a>1$, $a^{n!}$ will eventually outgrow $a^n!$ as $n \to \infty$. In general, $k! \le k^k$, so $(a^n)! \le (a^n)^{a^n} = a^{n \cdot a^n}$, and the exponent $n \cdot a^n$ grows slower than the exponent $n!$.

On the other hand, if $a$ is large and $n$ is small, then things can go the other way. You really want [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for factorials to say for sure.

---

Some more detail:

First, taking $n=a$ (when $a$ is reasonably large) is not large enough. Then $(a^a)!$ is a product of $a^a$ terms, most of which are close to $a^a$ in order of magnitude. On the other hand, $a^{a!}$ is a product of $a!$ (fewer) terms, which are only around $a$ (and therefore smaller).

For more accuracy, if we approximate $n! \approx (\frac ne)^n$ and compare it to $n a^n$ as we do in the argument above, then we see that we want $a < \frac ne$ or $n > e \cdot a$. Just taking $n = \lceil e a\rceil$ doesn't always work, since we took some approximations, but that tells us about how big $n$ has to be.

Comment: Say we are given an $a >1$. Is there a way to determine how large $n$ has to be for $a^{n!}>a^n!$ perhaps dependant on $a$?

Comment: You'll get no good exact rule. I will edit to say more about the ballpark range.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details! I see we lose a bit of certainity due to approximation which seems unavoidable. However wouldn't it be better to compare $\sqrt{n}(n/e)^n$ with $na^n$? This is also closer to the Stirling approximation it seems. 
Also how does one prove $n \cdot a^n$ grows slower than $n!$? I can't seem to make it work with induction like with the other claim: $k! \leq k^k$

Comment: It would be better to use $\sqrt n (\frac ne)^n$, but I am already being sloppier than that by ignoring the $n$ in front of $n a^n$. As for your second question: to show that $n a^n$ grows slower than $n!$, or $a^n$ slower than $(n-1)!$, note that $a^n$ multiplies by a fixed factor $a$ whenever we increment $n$, and $(n-1)!$ multiplies by a linearly growing factor.

Answer (score 3):

Since $k!<k^k$ if $k\ge2$,$$(a^n)!<a^{na^n}<a^{n!}$$for sufficiently large $n$.